# EF Core Include with FromSql extension without sub SELECT

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have some query to get companies from database like this:

```
var fullTextSearchVal = "test";
var sql = $"SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE CONTAINS(*, '\"*{fullTextSearchVal}*\"')";
var result = _context.Companies.Include(i => i.Address).FromSql(sql).ToList();
```

It works well, but have a little problem after I run Sql Server Profiler and check selector. It's look like this:

```
SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[AddressId], [i].[Email], [i].[Name], [i].[PhoneNumber], [i.Address].[Id], [i.Address].[Address], [i.Address].[City], [i.Address].[Country], [i.Address].[ZipCode]
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"*test*"')
) AS [i]
LEFT JOIN [Address] AS [i.Address] ON [i].[AddressId] = [i.Address].[Id]
```

The problem is in selector. Can I get query like following using Include and FromSql extensions(without sub SELECT)?

```
SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[AddressId], [i].[Email], [i].[Name], [i].[PhoneNumber], [i.Address].[Id], [i.Address].[Address], [i.Address].[City], [i.Address].[Country], [i.Address].[ZipCode]
FROM [Companies] AS [i]
LEFT JOIN [Address] AS [i.Address] ON [i].[AddressId] = [i.Address].[Id]
WHERE CONTAINS([i].*, '"*test*"')
```